# Ролик с youtube внутри Android-приложения

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

Как добавить ролик с YouTube, чтобы он проигрывался непосредственно внутри Android-приложения.(Внутри интерфейса)

Вариант через Intent не подойдет(другие задачи).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У ютуба есть sdk. В sdk есть ютубовский плеер. 
[YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)
Вот небольшой [видео туториал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJ7BoNG-r2c)